# Polymorphism Call

Tags: java, polymorphism

Please Help me in my code. This is polymorphism! I can't call all my class as you can see below, only the addition shows the output. I need some explanation too because I really need to know how this happened. 
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;



class Variation{

  public void reality(){

}

    public int reality(int n1,int n2,int n3,int n4,int n5){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers for addition: ");
    n1=keyboard.nextInt();
    n2=keyboard.nextInt();
    n3=keyboard.nextInt();
    n4=keyboard.nextInt();
    n5=keyboard.nextInt();

    int sum=n1+n2+n3+n4+n5;
    System.out.println("The answer is: "+sum);
    return sum;
}   
}

    class multi extends Variation{


    public double reality(double n1,double n2, double n3, double n4, double n5){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers for multiplication: ");
    n1=keyboard.nextInt();
    n2=keyboard.nextInt();
    n3=keyboard.nextInt();
    n4=keyboard.nextInt();
    n5=keyboard.nextInt();

    double prod=n1*n2*n3*n4*n5;
    System.out.println("The answer is: "+prod);  
    return prod;
}  
}

    class sub extends Variation{

    public int reality(int n1,int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 5 numbers for Subtraction: ");
    n1=keyboard.nextInt();
    n2=keyboard.nextInt();
    n3=keyboard.nextInt();
    n4=keyboard.nextInt();
    n5=keyboard.nextInt();

    int diff=n1-n2-n3-n4-n5;
    System.out.println("The answer is: "+diff);
    return diff;
    }
}

class Calling
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n1=0,n2=0,n3=0,n4=0,n5=0;

    Variation variaTions = new Variation();

    System.out.println(variaTions.reality(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5));

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only ever create an instance of Variation.  You never create an instance of any of the derived classes.  So of course they won't be called.

Comment: WOW! I get it now. Thank you so much for your help, I'm done with my assignment.